# Why can I see two distinct /tmp dirs?

Tags: samba, arch-linux, cups, kerberos

## Problem

I am seeing two different `/tmp` directories. In a plain GNOME terminal `ls -lia /tmp` gives the following:

```
total 136
  5797 drwxrwxrwt 36 root root     780 Oct  5 20:57 .
     2 drwxr-xr-x 21 root root    4096 Oct  5 19:48 ..
 ...snip...
 32824 -rw-------  1 me   users   1872 Oct  5 18:04 krb5cc_1000
 ...snip...
```

In a script started by `cupsd`, `ls -lia /tmp >> /test.log` gives a different a different folder with a different inode!

```
total 4
127684 drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   40 Oct  5 19:57 .
     2 drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 Oct  5 19:48 ..
```

In particular, I get `klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)`

## Background

I'm using Kerberos authentication with a shared samba printer. This requires running smbspool as my user instead of lp, so it can read `/tmp/krb5cc_1000`. I used the hacked smb script in http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/cups-printing-from-ad-integrated-workstation-to-ad-print-shares-using-kerberos-auth-722301/ to achieve this.

Here's my `/usr/lib/cups/backend/ksmb`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'network smb "Unknown" "Windows Printer via SAMBA"'
ls -lia /tmp &>> /test.log
su $2 -c "klist &>> /test.log"
su -c "/usr/bin/smbspool $1 $2 \"$3\" $4 \"$5\"" $2
```

Unfortunately, from the script's perspective, /tmp/krb5cc_1000 does not exist, and the authentication fails.

I'm running Arch x64, systemd, GNOME 3. I initially guessed there was something strange going on with `/tmp` being a `tmpfs`. However, I get the same failure when I comment out the tmpfs mount in fstab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a chroot side effect. In which case 
`find / -inum 127684` tells you where this /tmp is located.

Comment: What chroot? Does cupsd run a chroot by default for some reason?

Comment: I might, that's a wild guess. Did you run the command I suggested to figure it out ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The `find` command pointed to `/tmp/systemd-private-XXXXXX`. It turns out that systemd gave cupsd its own private tmp dir. I fixed my issue by disabling PrivateTmp in `/etc/systemd/system/printer.target.wants/cups.service` and restarting cups.